# How to get old versions of Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, email-client

Does anyone know where I can download a copy of Outlook 2003 and earlier?

Microsoft obviously wants to sell only their newer product on their website; Microsoft Download cCenter has a ton of product updates, but not the actual base install itself. Of course I may be overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TechNet or MSDN subscription is the only Microsoft sanctioned way. You can get TechNet pretty cheaply.

Comment: I looked on there and could only find updates, service packs and add-ons. No actual product download. Am I overlooking anything here?

Comment: Yes, look at this link: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/7/8/C78DB720-88CB-455E-AA0E-A087CB332A23/TechNet_Product_List.xlsx

Comment: Great - that's it. Thx! (Aside: For other users looking for the TechNet subscription, I recommend just searching on an SE "TechNet Subscription" - it's buried in the site.)

Comment: Okay, it's about £100 per year. But is the software available in that giant list all for free during that year? Unfortunately, it seems as if they only have Office (containing Outlook), rather than Outlook alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Outlook 2003 and 2007 on Amazon and eBay too. See this for example:
[http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-Outlook-2003-OLD-VERSION/dp/B0000AZJVF](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000AZJVF)

From $45 (open box) up to $116.99 (new).

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the full version Office contain Outlook?  I think you could probably get a copy of Office 2003 and install Outlook that way.